# Convergence of minimiser of empirical risk to minimiser of population risk

Tags: st.statistics, limits-and-convergence, machine-learning

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \mu$ be some random elements of a space $\mathcal{X}$. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space of functions $f: S \to \Re$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_H$.

Let $\|f^*\|_{L_2(\mu)} < \infty$ and $\lambda > 0$ and suppose, for simplicity, that the following minimisation problems have unique solutions, the empirical least squares problem
$$
   \hat{f} = \operatorname*{argmin}_{h\in H} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (h(x_i) - f^*(x_i))^2 + \lambda \|h\|_H^2
$$
and the population least squares problem
$$
   f = \operatorname*{argmin}_{h\in H} \|h - f^*\|_{L_2(\mu)}^2 + \lambda \|h\|_H^2.
$$

Under what conditions is the following true as $n\to\infty$

$$
  \mathbb{E}\|\hat{f} - f\|_{L_2(\mu)} \to 0
$$

and does it occur with a $1/\sqrt n$ rate?

I feel that this should be a standard result, so would appreciate a reference.

Comment: I changed $$f = \operatorname{argmin}_{h\in H} ||h - f^*||_{L_2(\mu)}^2 + \lambda ||h||_H^2.$$ to $$ f = \operatorname*{argmin}_{h\in H} \|h - f^*\|_{L_2(\mu)}^2 + \lambda \|h\|_H^2. $$ The subscript under $\operatorname{argmin}$ is not the only thing that changed. If the difference between $||a||$ and $\|a\|$ is not conspicuous enough to you, look at $||a|| ||b||,$ coded as `||a|| ||b||`, versus $\|a\|\|b\|,$ coded as `\|a\|\|b\|`. $\qquad$